# A company I just had an interview with is also about hold a job fair what should I do?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

I just recently had an interview with a company. The interview went very well, near the end I was given more detailed info about the position that I was being interviewed for. I was also told that they are set to have a job fair and that if I'd like I could go and visit and talk with some of the managers who know more about the position. That kinda confused  me.  So should I go or is not important for me to go.. would it be a good look to go? And also if I did go what do I do.. Because I've already been interviewed!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I was also told that they are set to have a job fair and that if I'd
>   like I could go and visit and talk with some of the managers who know
>   more about the position. That kinda confused me. So should I go or is
>   not important for me to go.. would it be a good look to go? And also
>   if I did go what do I do.. Because I've already been interviewed!

They were hinting that you should go and talk to some of the managers at the job fair.

That's what you should do. Find some that know more about the position, and with whom you haven't already spoken. Learn more about the position. Show enthusiasm.

It would help you decide if this is the kind of company, and if these are the kind of managers, you'd want to work with. And it would look good that you cared enough to attend.

Comment: Thank you, I kinda thought that but wasn't sure. I also was wondering that when going to the Job-Fair if I still needed to bring my resume.

Comment: @Dee Can't hurt. Take a good few copies, the managers there may find it helpful to have it there in front of them. Also, if there are a few other companies there you may find interesting, you could always go see them too...

Comment: Thank you all! I will keep yall posted as my interview was on the 5th and the  Job-fair is being held tomorrow for one company. Hope all goes well!

Comment: Have a few questions prepared - things that will help you determine if this company is a good fit for you, in terms of culture, style, etc. Don't pester the people you meet if they are busy, but if they give you an opportunity to ask questions (sounds like they will), it will be in your favor to have a few ready.

Comment: (UPDATE) Thanks so much everyone, I didn't get the chance to ask anyone any questions however I was offered the position and I took them up on thier offer! Again  thank you all again!